# Oracle Pivot - Assign Column Name without quotes

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a query:

```
select * from (
select 
ab_id, abc_metric, abc_value from TABLE1)
PIVOT(
min(abc_value)
FOR abc_metric IN ('Catalog','Fruit Type')); -- I have 50 such columns
```

This produces a table:

```
ab_id     'Catalog'      'Fruit Type'
1         a               b
2         c               d
```

I want the table with columns without quotes and separated by `_`

```
ab_id     catalog        fruit_type
1         a               b
2         c               d
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add `AS` and alias inside `PIVOT`:

```
select * 
from (select ab_id, abc_metric, abc_value from TABLE1)
PIVOT(min(abc_value)
  FOR abc_metric IN ('Catalog' AS Catalog,'Fruit Type' AS Fruit_type)
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=324747135b65f33aad087fbac1a28433)**

Comment: Is there a way to automate it?

Comment: @dang Which part do you want to automate? Aliases have to be added automatically. Same as values are not dynamically added, the aliases should be provided in advance

Answer (score 2):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select ab_id,
       max(case when abc_metric = 'Catalog' then abc_value end) as catalog,
       max(case when abc_metric = 'Fruit Type' then abc_value end) as fruit_type
from TABLE1
group by ab_id
```

Comment: Why to use different approach when Oracle provides aliasing inside Pivot?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda . . . I am basically anti-`pivot`.  It is unnecessary syntax.

Comment:  for `anti-pivot`  :) Still Oracle approach is not great, not terrible